# My h1 tag link appear a underline when hover that I didn't add

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My h1 tag link appear a blue underline that I did not add.I already set `text-decoration` to `none`,but it still appear a blue line when hover.Here is my code.

**CSS**

```
h1{
font-family:'Oxygen';
color:#000;
font-size:100px;
text-align:center;
margin-top:80px;
font-weight:50;
border:5px black solid;
text-decoration:none;
}
h1:hover{
color:#fff;
border:5px solid white;
text-decoration:none;
}
#h1{
height:100px;
width:600px;

margin:auto;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div data-speed="1.2" data-type="background" id="search-background" class="clearfix"  style="background-attachment:fixed;">
<div id="h1">
<a href="#about"><h1>Joomgame</h1></a>
</div>
<p>Front-End Devoloper</p>
        </div>
```

Comment: That's because it's inside the `<a>` tag

Comment: I think your anchor tag css overrides your h1 tag css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the `text-decoration` to the `a` http://jsfiddle.net/725tenf1/

```
#h1 a{
text-decoration:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because it's inside the `<a>` tag

Use this CSS:

```
a > h1 {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```